# Data preview of the dataflow source only show first row

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to read a .csv file.
When I preview the data, only the first row shows up.
Experimented with different row delimiters, but no success...

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTSnU.png)

[data preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en4sb.png)

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJWdB.png)

Comment: Could you please add what is your source?  Blob storage or ADLS? and also a picture of original dataset that you want to get?

Comment: Hi, the source is blob storage. The original dataset is a delimited text file: https://i.imgur.com/7G2u29O.png

Comment: Changing the encoding to utf-16be show multiple lines, but the output seems to be unreadable https://i.imgur.com/6Ha3aVl.png

Comment: I reproduced the above in my environment and I am able to get all the rows with same source settings in dataflow https://i.imgur.com/006Y0XF.png

Comment: Have you tried with Normal Delimitedtext dataset rather than Inline Delimited dataset? it results same?

Comment: Yes, tried with both. Same result

Comment: In the Data preview Image, col_2 is High Frequency and in your original dataset it is LOW FREQUENCY. Could you please confirm whether both datasets are same or not?

Comment: Hi, I probably took a screenshot from a different file, but i issue occurs on every file.

Comment: For Testing purpose, try to transform any one file to sink and check the sink file in the blob.